# C/C++ string memory allocation

Tags: c++, string, stm32

I've just recently begun with C/C++ development on an embedded system (ARM - STM32F4 to be more specific) and I am now having almost classical problems of someone who isn't used to C or low level memory managment.

Basically I have a class MenuOption that inherits some field from some other class and basically looks like this:

```
...
char text[20];
...
void MenuOption::setText(const char* text1)
{
  clearCurrent();
  needsUpdate = true;

  strncpy(text, text1, 20);
  width = font->FontWidth*strlen(text);
}
```

The constructor for this class calls that setText method to store the text. This works fine if I use it like this inside a main function:

```
std::vector<MenuOption *> mainMenuOptions;
MenuOption* op1 = new MenuOption(13, 15, "Info", WHITE, BLACK);
op1->setSelected(true);
mainMenuOptions.push_back(op1);
```

But it fails when I want to use it like this:

```
std::vector<MenuOption *> options;
for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); i++)
{
  Thing *th = things[i];
  ... do some stuff with th ...
  MenuOption* op = new MenuOption(190, 38+25*i, "test", WHITE, BLACK);
  options.push_back(op);
}
```

This fails (debugger sort of stalls) at the `MenuOption* op ...` line. Now I am guessing that this isn't something that I should be doing. But I can't seem to find a working solution.

EDIT:

To answer everyones questions. This does in fact compile with a C++ compiler. GCC using C++11 dialect.

There is a reason why I am using C strings instead of std::string. I am using a few C libraries that need C strings. And whenever I tried to convert that string into a C string inside a FreeRTOS task the thing would fail. The same problem as now actually.

No other breakpoint inside the task will trigger after it reaches that constructor line. I can't step in or skip a line or anything like that at that line. I have a feeling it gets caught by a hard_fault interrupt handler. Other tasks would continue to run. That's the problem. There are no errors or anything that would point me to the cause. The same problem was when I was using std::string when I tried to create a new MenuOption inside a FreeRTOS task. The thing works if I remove the string from the constructor. So I am guessing that it has something to do with strings.

As for string length. I know that strings used here will not be longer than 15 characters. I used those 5 characters for pure "backup"-

As for the `... do some stuff with th ...` that was just this: `th->flag = true;`. I didn't do anything more with it because of this problem.

Comment: If you don't think `... do some stuff with th ...` is involved in this, think again.

Comment: This is not `C` as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is not C++ either. Hence the infamous C/C++.

Comment: C++ using string functions from the C library... Fair enough, but since you're up for C++, consider using the C++ library instead (read std::string)...

Comment: `strncpy` does not guarantee termination. Are you aware of that?

Comment: What error do you get? I can see you may have problems with the strings, it's not a good idea to have a fixed array to store them.

Comment: @ventayol: It can be the best way to store some strings... if you know in advance how long they will be.

Comment: @Deduplicator It can be, but from the code he posted I can see they are not 20 characters long, so I guess it might be any length. Anyway, I would like to see the full code or the error to know what can happen.

Comment: @nwp This is c++ isn't it? because c is a subset of c++ (though i guess not always strictly speaking)

Comment: @James It looks like it would compile with a C++-compiler. But so does `inline asm(everything_written_in_assembler);`. I would argue that using the C or assembler subset of C++ does not count as C++ but it technically does.

Comment: I edited the original question to add more information.

Comment: You should be able to step with your debugger in "new", you make use of dynamic memory allocation, are you aware that the STM32F4 does not have a MMU and that its memory can therefore fragmentate easily? You should also add a "try catch" block around your dynamic memory allocations, it is possible they are failing. Are you using newlib? Are C++ exceptions activated?

Comment: @Étienne Thanks for the tip. The problem was actually with the new operator not with my string usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip posted in the comments by Étienne was actually what lead me to the answer. More specifically I found this: http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/October_2013/freertos_Using_C_std_vector_in_task_93928e86j.html

```
void *operator new(size_t size)
{
   void *p;

   if(uxTaskGetNumberOfTasks())
      p=pvPortMalloc(size);
   else
      p=malloc(size);

   return p;
}

void operator delete(void *p)
{
   if(uxTaskGetNumberOfTasks())
      vPortFree( p );
   else
      free( p );

   p = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped,  in newlib some functions are not implemented ("newlib stubs") to improve flexibility.